# What is a good way to extract 5 grouped 8 bits after clearing the first 2 groups first?

Tags: math, binary, computer-science

Given the following example

Given this hash

`90048143708691375074705520716729968351473889681930970060116675602760373567488` (this hash will always be the same length)

to binary this translates to

> 11000111 00010101 01110001 01110101 00000101 11001010 11111111
> 10110010 01010111 10001111 11111110 10001011 00111010 01010111
> 01010011 01101001 10001110 00110000 10100110 10000001 10011101
> 11010100 11101100 11010100 00111011 01110110 01011110 01111110
> 10101110 00100111 00000000 00000000

`hash = ((hash >> 16) << 16);`

I cleared two groups to set later depending on my implementation

I want to extract and mask the next 5 groups and those to **always** evaluate to 14 total decimals, as an example it would be something like this.

`[15][32][40][93][11][71][84]`

The current mask that I'm messing with is `0xFFFFFFFFFFA` but there have been edge cases where it doesnt equal to 14 total decimals but rather 13.

Advice would be appreciated!

Comment: What is a *group*? As best I can tell from your description it's just a byte. Why is your hash value expressed as a decimal? To extract and mask the bits you appear to want you simply do `(hash >> 16) & 0xffffffffff`.

Comment: It is completely unclear what you're trying to do.  What do you want your result to look like?

Comment: Groups as in bytes, yes that is correct.

What i want to the end result to be from those 5 bytes is an even number of groups of 2 digits like this 

but my problem is sometimes... there is 1 decimal missing as the example shows

[16][96][29][36][87][03]
[10][97][91][68][29][79]9